# Convert boolean expression to nand gate only. X = A'B'C+AB'C'+A'B'

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, nand, truth-table, common-gate

I have already made a diagram. However, it won't match the truth table that I have made, which I got from [image]the logic converter in multisim. Could you please help me out with where did I go wrong? Is it on my diagram or in my truth table?

[image]

Comment: The truth table is definitely wrong. For example the `110` line. The circuit seem to be oversized too. Note that the expression is not sufficiently minimized.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what can i do about it?

Comment: I presume this is an academic exercise? Then you should have learned how to minimize boolean functions and build truth tables.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It was difficult since my professor is not teaching at all. He just keeps on giving exercises and assessments. That's why I am here to ask guidance.

Comment: From the truth table, your output X is the NAND of three inputs A, B, C. You have far too many gates to implement this simple function.

Comment: Are you familiar with Karnaugh maps?

Comment: @philfreedenberg can you help me to reduce the gates?

Comment: @user28910 no i am not

Comment: Start by factoring B' from the expression for X. Then simplify the other factor.